# error 381 el indice de la matriz de propiedades no es valido

Tags: excel, vba

Buenas tardes estoy haciendo un listbox en vba excel para que guarde unos datos, sin embargo me aparece ese error.

Todas las variables son públicas e incluso las he puesto todas tipo variant.

```
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 4
ListBox1.AddItem
ListBox1.List(0, 0) = (UserForm1.TextBox5.Text)
ListBox1.List(0, 1) = ""
ListBox1.List(0, 2) = ""
ListBox1.List(0, 3) = UserForm1.precio_adquisicion

Do Until (ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount, 3) = UserForm1.valor_residual)
'For i = 2 To 100
ListBox1.AddItem
'variable = variable + 1
ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount, 0) = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, CDate(UserForm1.fecha_funcionamiento))
ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount, 1) = (UserForm1.precio_adquisicion - UserForm1.valor_residual) / UserForm1.años
acumulador_amortizacion = acumulador_amortizacion + ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount, 1)
ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount, 2) = acumulador_amortizacion
ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount, 3) = (ListBox1.List((ListBox1.ListCount - 1), 3) - ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount, 1))
'Next
Loop

End Sub
```

He probado a sustituir el listcount por una variable que vaya incrementando 1 y nada

Comment: Si la lista es basada en 0, ListBox1.ListCount va a ser 1 más como cuanto está en la lista.

Comment: Estimado amigo, mil gracias llevo muchas horas para seleccionar algo tan básico ahora me da otro error en este linea `ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) - ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1)
` No se puede configurar la propiedad list los tipos no coinciden. He probado a cambiar las variables a double e integer y nada

Comment: No me sorpresa, list() es un object de tipo object.  Hay que convertirlo hasta int para suma y resta.

Comment: Gracias compañero! Ya va de lujo, te dejo por aquí otro problema por si pudieras echarme una mano [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320808/error-9-subindice-fuera-del-intervalo]

Comment: @Duston Todo lo que has dicho es una respuesta válida. Deberías escribir la respuesta para que se acepte y poder cerrar la pregunta.